# How can I make IStringLocalizer work in my controllers?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I recently upgraded a .NET project from netcoreapp2.0 to net6.0, and the localization setup is no longer working. It searches the IdentityServer.Resources.SharedResource location like it should, but it always returns with ResourceNotFound = true. The returned value is always "AlreadySignedIn" and it should be "This account is currently logged in. Logging in anyway will end the previous session." I know this is a lot of text, but I'm not sure where the problem is.

Here's a hypothetical example of how I expect to use it:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer;

    public AccountController(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AlreadySignedIn(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("AlreadySignedIn", localizer["AlreadySignedIn"]);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is the project's Startup.cs file

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(
                new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot")));

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication().AddScheme<CookieAuthenticationOptions, DatabaseSessionAuthenticator>("DatabaseSession", options => 
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/api/Session/Unauthorized";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/Session/Unauthorized";
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/api/Session/Unauthorized";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/Session/AccessDenied";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(Configuration.GetValue<int>("SessionTimeoutHours"));
                options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(48));

            services.AddAuthorization(options => {

                options.AddPolicy("SuperUser", policy => policy
                    .RequireClaim("userclass", "Super"));

            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
            services.AddControllers(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

            services.AddLocalization(o => 
            {
                o.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
            });

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US", "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });
            
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>>());

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });


            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new TimeSpan(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 1, seconds: 30);
                    //spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the contents of SharedResource.cs

```
namespace IdentityServer
{
    public class SharedResource
    {
    }
}
```

This is the contents of SharedResource.resx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <!-- 
    Microsoft ResX Schema 
    
    Version 2.0
    
    The primary goals of this format is to allow a simple XML format 
    that is mostly human readable. The generation and parsing of the 
    various data types are done through the TypeConverter classes 
    associated with the data types.
    
    Example:
    
    ... ado.net/XML headers & schema ...
    <resheader name="resmimetype">text/microsoft-resx</resheader>
    <resheader name="version">2.0</resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, ...</resheader>
    <data name="Name1"><value>this is my long string</value><comment>this is a comment</comment></data>
    <data name="Color1" type="System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing">Blue</data>
    <data name="Bitmap1" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded serialized .NET Framework object]</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Icon1" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
        <value>[base64 mime encoded string representing a byte array form of the .NET Framework object]</value>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
    </data>
                
    There are any number of "resheader" rows that contain simple 
    name/value pairs.
    
    Each data row contains a name, and value. The row also contains a 
    type or mimetype. Type corresponds to a .NET class that support 
    text/value conversion through the TypeConverter architecture. 
    Classes that don't support this are serialized and stored with the 
    mimetype set.
    
    The mimetype is used for serialized objects, and tells the 
    ResXResourceReader how to depersist the object. This is currently not 
    extensible. For a given mimetype the value must be set accordingly:
    
    Note - application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64 is the format 
    that the ResXResourceWriter will generate, however the reader can 
    read any of the formats listed below.
    
    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.
    
    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.soap.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized with 
            : System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.

    mimetype: application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64
    value   : The object must be serialized into a byte array 
            : using a System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
            : and then encoded with base64 encoding.
    -->
  <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="Concurrency" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Concurrency Violation.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Inactive" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This user account is no longer active. You can no longer log in with this account.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidClientId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid Client Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidContactId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid Contact Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidLicenseApplicationId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid License Application Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidLicenseEntityId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid License Entity Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidLicenseId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid License Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidLicenseModuleId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid License Module Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidSuperUserDelete" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Deleting User is not allowed.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidUserClassUpdate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Updating User Class is not allowed.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidUserId" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid User Id.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidUserNamePassword" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid User Name/Password</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Lockout" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This user account has been locked out due to too many failed login attempts. You can log in after a few minutes.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="NotAllowedConcurrent" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>All concurrent licenses are being used. You cannot log in with this concurrent user account until a license becomes available.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="NotAllowedNamed" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>All named licenses are being used. You cannot log in with this named user account until a license becomes available.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="AlreadySignedIn" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This account is currently logged in. Logging in anyway will end the previous session.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="NotAllowedTemporaryExpiryDate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This user account is no longer active. You can no longer log in with this account.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="NotAllowedTemporaryStartDate" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This user account is not yet active. You can not log in with this account until {0}.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="UserLimitExceeded" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>User Limit Reached.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="ApplicationNameApplicationURL" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Application Name, Application URL and application Icon already exist.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="InvalidSecurityTokens" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid Security Token</value>
  </data>
  <data name="EmailIDExist" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Email already in use.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="LocalhostURL" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>http://localhost:5000</value>
  </data>
  <data name="UserNameExist" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>User name already in use.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="UserEmailExist" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Email already in use.</value>
  </data>
  <data name="SInvalidclientID" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Invalid user Id</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

This is the project's file structure

[image: Project File Structure]